# Dropping table in Rails 5 - Adding it back later throws table already exists error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I am building an application with Rails 5 and SQLite. I was trying to make a table for a many to many relationship and created a join table without the 'CreateModelXModelYJoinTable', rather I created a migration with two foreign keys. Once I realized my mistake, I dropped the table via a migration and recreated it with the above syntax, but now when I migrate I am getting this error:

```
SQLite3::SQLException: table "ingredients_recipes" already exists
```

Here are the three offending migrations in order:

```
class CreateIngredientRecipes < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
 def change
   create_table :ingredient_recipes do |t|
     t.references :recipe, foreign_key: true
     t.references :ingredient, foreign_key: true

     t.timestamps
   end
 end
end



class DropIngredientsRecipes < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
 def change
   drop_table :ingredient_recipes
 end
end


class CreateIngredientsRecipesJoinTable < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
 def change
   create_join_table :ingredients, :recipes


    create_join_table :ingredients, :recipes do |t|
       t.index :ingredient_id
       t.index :recipe_id
    end
  end
end
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. I checked in the console and the association is no longer there. Even went into rails db and listed the tables and it is not there. Looked everywhere for a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake is you have the `create_join_table` repeated **twice**:

Your code:

```
class CreateIngredientsRecipesJoinTable < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
 def change
   create_join_table :ingredients, :recipes


    create_join_table :ingredients, :recipes do |t|
       t.index :ingredient_id
       t.index :recipe_id
    end
  end
end
```

It should be :

```
class CreateIngredientsRecipesJoinTable < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
 def change
    create_join_table :ingredients, :recipes do |t|
       t.index :ingredient_id
       t.index :recipe_id
    end
  end
end
```

You can notice that the created Join table is `ingredients_recipes` and not `ingredient_recipes`, which explains the issue.